# How to detect overscroll in Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview, overscroll

I'd like to show/hide a view when the user over scroll the listview.

How can I detect the over-scroll? Is there any listener? 
I've tried `OnScrollListener` but it only notifies about `onScrollStateChanged` and `onScroll`

Comment: What have you done uptill now ? Please post some code atleast.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can override the method [onOverScrolled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29), as it `respond to the results of an over-scroll operation.`

Comment: Indeed. you'll have to subclass it and add the new class instead of the regular ListView

Comment: I've been looking for this so long and it turns out to be so simple, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just a little more complete answer :

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);

    View view = (View) getChildAt(getChildCount()-1);
    int diff = (view.getBottom()-(getHeight()+getScrollY()));

    if(diff==0) {
           //overscroll on bottom
       } else {
           //overscroll on top
       }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

scrollY = non-Zero and clampedY = true --> OverScroll state occure While Scrolling bottom to top

scrollY = Zero and clampedY = true --> OverScroll state occure While Scrolling top to bottom

so

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled(int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX, scrollY, clampedX, clampedY);

    if(clampedY){
        if(scrollY==0){
            //over Scroll at top
        }else {
            //over Scroll at Bottom
        }
    }
}
```