# ListView listener for specific action sequence

Tags: android, android-listview

Is there  the way to listen the following specifiс action sequence: long click on listview item and  top overscroll of listview?

Comment: Did you look at the documentation to see what you could find?

Comment: If answer can be find in doceumentation provide a links, please.

Answer (score 0):

Go to [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for ListView references.

And yes...there is a property **setOnLongClickListener** etc...
Please check the link

Comment: and listview overscroll action? I need to listen sequence of longclick and next overscroll action?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334323/how-to-detect-overscroll-in-android

Comment: why to type the same thing again if it is already present?
Also, there may be some more useful stuff in the link which can be helpful. I think its better to redirect user to the already present answer than to re-write the entire thing again..

Comment: The link is not bad, it's just that it should be a comment, not a answer which you instantly solicit votes for.